# Scraping informations with Beautiful Soup in same name tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape informations from an html page with Beautiful Soup in Python and all the information I need are in a same name tag> How can I differentiate each information I need ?

[image]
All the information I need are in different class="hAyfc" tags.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the help file. It is the custom on StackOverflow for those who ask questions to post code showing the attempt they have made to solve problems for themselves. Would you please post the code you have written for this problem and ask a question relating to that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be in order.you just need to take the result out because the order of the results is the same as the order in html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class = "hAyfc">
    <div class = "BgcNfc">pro </div>
    <span class = "htlgb">
        <div>
            <span class = "htlgb">
                codeA
            </span>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>

<div class = "hAyfc">
    <div class = "BgcNfc">pro </div>
    <span class = "htlgb">
        <div>
            <span class = "htlgb">
                codeB
            </span>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
result = [e.text for e in bs.find_all("div",{"class":"hAyfc"})]
print(result)
```